# UITableView titleForSection font

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder, nsstring

A quick question, for a quick answer (since I'm not finding any):

Is there a way to change the font of the section's title (given by titleForSection) in iPhone?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You'll have to use the `viewForHeaderInSection:` method and provide your own view. Luckily this can be a UILabel with a specified font, so you can do it quite easily.

Answer (score 39):

Thanks Jasarien! You were absolutely right.

I leave my code here to help someone with the same problem:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

   NSString *sectionTitle = @"Just a title";

    // Create label with section title
    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 284, 23);
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    label.text = sectionTitle;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Create header view and add label as a subview
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
    [view autorelease];
    [view addSubview:label];

    return view;
}
```

Comment: This is great, however, UILabel is a direct subclass of UIView, so you don't really need to create a 'header' view and add the label as a subview. You can simply return the label itself as the header view.

Comment: If you return the label itself as the header, how would you give it some offset on the left? Changing the origin.x of the label frame in that case does not work..

Comment: to set text of the section title: `label.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];`

Comment: If you use Interface Builder to make your table, you'll also have to change the size of the section height in the Attributes Inspector.

Answer (score 5):

You have to override

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

to give required height for the section title. Else it will overlap with the cell.

Answer (score 3):

viewForHeaderInSection might work fine... but here's an alternative that works fine for me (Xcode 5 and IOS7 target):

```
// To set the background color and text color of the Table Headers
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Background color
    view.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.329 green:0.557 blue:0.827 alpha:1.000];

    // Text Color & Alignment
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    [header.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [header.textLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    // Text Font
    UIFont *saveFont = header.textLabel.font;
    [header.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:saveFont.fontName size:18.0]];

    // Another way to set the background color
    // Note: does not preserve gradient effect of original heade!r
    // header.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

[Here's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEimo.png)